# Não consigo utilizar variável no html utilizando EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Já olhei alguns blogs e até a documentação mas confesso que ainda não entendi como utilizar EJS e resolver meu problema.

No código abaixo após a conexão com DB salvo o nome do usuário na variável note e envio para poder ser utilizada quando a página notepad for renderizada (até aqui tudo funcionando)

```
router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
    let name = req.body
    let note = await Notepad.find({nameUser: name})
     if(note){  
        try {
         res.render('pages/notes/notepad.ejs', {note})
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).render('pages/error.ejs', {error})
        }   
    }else{  
        console.log('erro')
        let msg = 'Não há notepad'
        res.status(200).render('pages/notes/notepad', {msg})
    }

})
```

No HTML tudo renderiza mas quando tento acessar note.id na linha 4 (porque quero mandar o Id na rota) não consigo já quando acesso a mesma dentro do forEach funciona normal.Eu até tentei colocar o código que está entre as tags  dentro de um For() mas também não funcionou.

```
<%- include('../../layouts/header.ejs', {title: 'Notepad'}) %>
<%- include('../../layouts/menu.ejs') %>

<a class="button is-primary" href="/notepad/:<%= note.id %>">
  <strong>New note</strong>
</a>

<% note.forEach(note => { %>

    <div class="card  column is-half" >
        <header class="card-header">
          <p class="card-header-title">
            <%= note.name %>
            <%= note.id %>
          </p>
        </header>
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="content">
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="card-footer">
          <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Save</a>
        </footer>
      </div>

<% }) %>
<%- include('../../layouts/footer.ejs') %>
```

Só é possível acessar a variável no HTML através de um loop?

Comment: seu `note` é um array? ja tentou `note[0].id`

Comment: @BernardoLopes, sim é um array mas isso não funciona.